# visual studio 2022 17.3 xamarin android Detecting existing process

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2022

With the latest visual studio 2022 17.3.0 update, my xamarin native app can't be started in debug as I keep getting this message:
Forwarding debugger port 8811
Detecting existing process

I have tried to clean and unistall app from the phone.
Same project works fine on visual studio 2019.

Thanks

Comment: Hi,you can try to uninstall the app from the device and clear the cache data. Then re-dubug the project. If it doesn't work, try another emulator or device for test.

Comment: Still an issue. Also with 17.3.1 update.

Comment: Is it showing the same issue by using another physical device or emulator?

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT I am having this issue also, and I just tried the steps that you suggested to no avail. Seeing the same issue on multiple devices, and after clearing cache and uninstalling app.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT can you tell me if there's a ticket for this issue in the Microsoft system? This is a big problem for my team.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just activate Use Fast Deployment, i was having the same issue, but i activated this option, and now works!!! [image]

Comment: Super, that did it for me. Thanks.

Comment: This might be a workaround, but not really a fix, as this seems to be a bug in version 17.3.x of VS 2022. I actually can't use fast deployment because I need system permissions in my app, so this is not a fix for me.

Comment: you're right, it's only a workaround but at least we can advance in our pending projects, i don't know why the xamarin team always release a new xamarin version with a lot of bugs

Comment: VS for Mac 17.3.5 workaround worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

I am also experiencing this.  Multiple devices.  I can use Visual Studio 2019 and it works fine.  It was working with Visual Studio 2022 until the last update.  Tried cleaning solution, manually deleting obj directories, manually uninstalling from device, etc.

Main errors I get are...

[monodroid] Creating public update directory: `/data/user/0/com.lathem.payclock/files/.__override__`
[art] Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
[monodroid-debug] Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:8864,server=y,embedding=1
[monodroid-assembly] Failed to load managed assembly 'mscorlib.dll'. Internal error
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly mscorlib.dll
[mono] The assembly mscorlib.dll was not found or could not be loaded.
[mono] It should have been installed in the `/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/sdks/out/android-armeabi-v7a-release/lib/mono/2.1/mscorlib.dll' directory.

And this...

Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
at System.String.Format(String format, Object[] args)
at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidLogger.LogError(String task, String format, Object[] args) in D:\a_work\1\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidLogger.cs:line 63
at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass118_0.b__0() in D:\a_work\1\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidDevice.cs:line 1012